# A puzzle from probability

Tags: probability

There are 5 balls in a bag. One ball is picked and it is found to be red. What is the probability that all the balls in the bag are red?

There is no other detail mentioned in this question.

I tried Bayes' Theorem but got stuck. But may be this problem doesn't require Bayes' theorem. Can someone please help me solve this problem?

Comment: The question is unanswerable in its current state.

Comment: We'll need to know the probability that one ball picked from the five is red.

Comment: **If** the prior distribution is unknown, it may be possible that this question is asked in the context of having the "student" practice doing a question in which the prior is not known (this is common enough in scientific applications that it may be something taught in classes). In which case you may need to read up on uninformative priors such as [principle of insufficient reason](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_indifference) or the [Jeffreys prior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffreys_prior).

Answer (score 1):

Let the number of red balls in the bag be K, and the event that the first ball drawn from the bag is red be denoted by U, you are asking for:
$$
p(K=5|U)=\frac{p(U|K=5)p(K=5)}{p(U)}=\frac{p(K=5)}{\sum_{i=1}^5 p(U|K=i)p(K=i)}
$$
To proceed further you need to know the initial pmf for K, that is you need to know how the bag was prepared.

Note the terms $p(K=k)$ in the above denote the prior probabilities for $K$ before the observation $U$.